# What is the meaning behind a drummer calling his style of playing as 'orchestrational' (as opposed to 'strict time')?

Tags: drums, black-sabbath

I was watching an interview with Black Sabbath's drummer Bill Ward and he said that his drumming style is orchestrational as opposed to strict time.  What does he mean by 'orchestrational'? How does it differ from ‘strict time’?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as requested by OP, turning this comment into an answer :

On the strict meaning of the word, it suggests he is more than just laying down/keeping the beat, but rather has some role in how the piece is orchestrated.

If I knew  Black Sabbath's music in more depth, rather than part of the soundtrack of my life,  I could expand the answer with examples.